# Is there a pandas filter that allows any value?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Is there a pandas filter that allows any value?

```
df[df['column'] == ANYTHING]
```

Basically I'm building a bokeh plot with widgets to filter a dataframe but I don't want to add a "No filter" option in my dataframe because it would become really large if I would do that.

Comment: How do you know when you would want to compare "ANYTHING" to `df.column`?

Comment: `df[df['column'] != None]`?